# Unsure when to use targets or configurations in Xcode

Tags: xcode, configuration, target

Can somebody give me a clear and intuitive example when I should prefer creating a new target vs creating a new configuration in Xcode?

For example, when beta-testing with TestFlight; should I create a new "TestFlight" target to include all the TestFlight code or should I create a new "Beta" configuration and then in code do:

```
#ifdef CONFIGURATION_Beta
    [TestFlight takeOff:@"Insert your Team Token here"];
#endif
```

So, when is it more appropriate to use targets over configurations and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can somebody give me a clear and intuitive example when I should prefer creating a new target vs creating a new configuration in Xcode?

Here you go,,,

Targets are for for controlling the addition of different assets and code for different products.

For example let say you want to have 2 apps, a iphone/itouch version and a separate target for iPad, not a universal app.  When you add assets for iphone only check the iphone target. When you add assets for the ipad app check the ipad target. You compile compile test and release each target separately. Testflight would be in both. You can also have different compiler settings for additional debugging enabled.

For each you want to what a configurations for CONFIGURATION_Beta and CONFIGURATION_Store.
Now assume you only want testflight in beta and not in store version that is where configurations come in to play.

```
#ifdef CONFIGURATION_Beta
    [TestFlight takeOff:@"Insert your Team Beta Token here"];
#endif

#ifdef CONFIGURATION_Store
// No test flight, so no code added to app
#endif
```

The linker will optimize and not include the testfight code in the binary for the store version.

Comment: Any questions about this I use it all the time.